# Redis - Avoid Data Loss using Cluster (Using Gossip Protocol)

Tags: kubernetes, mariadb, hazelcast, airflow-scheduler, redis-cluster

We would like to deploy Airflow application on Kubernetes on 2 Data centers.

Airflow Schedular container generates DAGs for every 1min, 5mins and 10 mins. These DAGs are the tasks that will be assigned to Airflow Worker container.

In the process of assigning tasks to Airflow worker, Airflow Schedular sends the data about tasks to both MariaDb (can be considered as a source of Truth) and Redis.

In MariaDB task can have one of the statuses '`queued`', '`running`', '`success`', '`failed`'. When tasks are in Redis it will be in the state of '`queued`'.

MariaDB maintains the same when it receives tasks from Airflow Schedular. when Redis handovers particular queued task
to Worker container, MariaDB changes that particular task status to 'running' and if it completes executing process, the task status in MariaDB will be changed to 'Success'.

**The actual problem:**

When Redis fails, we have queued tasks in MariaDB but we will lose data in Redis. When the k8s brings up new Redis server, it will lose previous tasks- here comes the *DATA LOSS*.

What can be the solution for this.

Can we use `Redis Clustering - Gossip protocol` to avoid data loss:

If yes, could you provide any documentation in resolving this problem using this protocol.
else provide the suggestions that suits to my environment and scenario.

Comment: It would be fine if you can suggest any Enterprise level solutions to rely on it for our scenario

Comment: Can someone give suggestions of using Hazelcast instead of Redis. Will that solve my problem or create new one?

Comment: Have you actually determined that Redis is necessary.

Comment: @RickJames James - Project is still in the research phase, Redis was proposed earlier but it is having some flaws when integrated with Airflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redis clustering would help with it, but it is a bit of a pain to set up and it's not a complete replacement for backups.

In your case a much simpler solution in my opinion would be to incorporate a recovery procedure in your redis pod startup. You do not have a permanent data loss as you have your MariaDB source of truth, so you can add an init containerthat runs a script to recover redis data from MariaDB.

Another approach that would limit your problem significantly would be to use a persistent volume to store redis data as redis can snapshot it's in-memory state in regular intervals. With use of StatefulSet instead of Deployment to manage your Redis node(s) pods would get the storage reattached on restart/rescheduling and you'd experiens no data loss (or at most the tiny window since the last snapshot)

Comment: We have the backup plan as incorporating a recovery procedure in my redis pod startup/Schedular can assign tasks to Redis as it has connection with MariaDB already. But it might be a complex piece!

For now, I would like to know more information about Redis Clustering to do POC. Could you suggest some documentation in setting up a cluster and how to bring up nodes manually without downtime on cluster (if possible).

We have not thought of persistant volumes but we are not much interested in storing the data on external volumes.

Comment: Can you provide more information on incorporating a recovery procedure in my redis pod startup.

Will that be good to incorporate recovery procedure on Airflow schedular (you can consider this aa a Producer component) or on the redis pod startup?

Could you guide me on this in detail manner.